# Item appears below the current item instead of next to it

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, react-hooks, react-router

I have 2 components:

When I had it as follows:

**Sidebar.js:**

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function Sidebar(){
    let history = useHistory();

    let SidebarClick = () =>{
        history.push("/some/link");
    };
    
    
    return(
         <div className="main_div">
            <div className="children_wrapper">
                <div className="div_item">
                    abc
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

In **Sidebar.scss** :

```
.main_div{
  width: 25%;
  position: sticky;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


.main_div .children_wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}


.children_wrapper .div_item{
  width: 100%;
  height: 7vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

In **App.js**:

When I called the component (Sidebar) like this inside of the main_app div, it appeared as desired where the sidebar is next to the main content:

```
<div className="app">
  
  <div className="main_app">
      <Sidebar /> 
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
In **App.scss**:  
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.app{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f0f2f5;
}

.main_app{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

It looked as desired.
Desired Image:
[image: desired layout]

However when I had it in a Route render prop as follows :

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
          <div className="app">
              
              <div className="actual_app">
                  <SideBar/>
                 
              </div>

              <Switch>
                  <Route path="/some/link" render={() => <Sidebar/>} />
              </Switch>

          </div>
      </Router>

  );
}
```

It appears below the current page instead of next to the sidebar.
[image: output]

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue but you also have some inconsistencies. For example, I was looking at your style to make sure that your div that has the sidebar and content is `flex`, and I see you have `.main_app` set to `flex` but I don't see that class being used anywhere in updated `App` component using the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property that keeps the two components on the same line is the
`display: flex;` line that is attached your main_app and that classname no longer exists. It looks like you changed the name to actual_app but the new component that you added is not within the actual_app div so the flex display is not applied to it.

When you add a flex display property to an element, it applies to all the components contained within that element, but not the element's own positioning (unlike the display properties "block" and "display-block").

You can either add the flex display to the app div, or move the new component within the actual_app div.